# How can one place multiple level 7 resonators on a portal?

Tags: ingress

I checked for a portal and found this scene:

[image: Multiple 7LVL resonators]

[Here](http://www.ingressguide.com/portals/leveling/) I found a phrase:

> A Player can have ONE L7 resonator on one Portal at one time.

By 'one time' is meant one time the portal is owned by that fraction or one something else?
Or it is a hack/bug/exploit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a result of Youpak using an ADA Refactor virus on the portal.
If you do that, all resonators and mods on the portal belong to you (if it's the same faction as you are) or one of special pseudo-players (`__ADA__` or `__JARVIS__`) if not.

Comment: Thanks! If I get right you can apply ADA Refactor only on enemy's portal so I don't understand what is the other part you mentioned (ADA and JARVIS pseudo-players) about?

Update:
Found this post: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119275/are-jarvis-virus-ada-refactors-useless-to-the-other-side
Explains my question...

Comment: @Vairis You can use Jarvis virus on a Resistance portal and ADA Refractor on a Enlightened portal no-matter what color you have. If the resulting portal has same color as you do, you will be the owner, otherwise Jarvis or _ADA_ will be the owner of the portal and it's resonators. This tactics is actually quite useful if you need to destroy your own faction's links standing in a way of something bigger.

Comment: It is also a smart way to create an L8 portal with only 2 L8 players :-)

Comment: I'd dispute the word "smart". You need 12 viruses for that. 1200 hacks, for building _one_ L8 portal?

Comment: Both of you are right. It is not smart when it is easier to gather other agents, but it is sometimes the only feasible way in some critical areas and circumstances.