# How can a portal have four mods from the same agent?

Tags: ingress

As far as I know one agent can only install two mods on a portal.

But I just came across a portal that has **four mods by the same agent**.

How's that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one place multiple level 7 resonators on a portal?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129752/how-can-one-place-multiple-level-7-resonators-on-a-portal)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens when an Enlightened agent uses a Jarvis Virus or a Resistance agent uses an ADA Refactor on a portal which already has four mods deployed; when that happens, the portal, all resonators and mods on the portal become owned by the agent who used the Virus / Refactor. (In the opposite case when an Enlightened agent uses a Refactor or a Resistance agent uses a Virus, the portal, the resonators and the mods become owned by __ADA__ or __JARVIS__ respectively).

Comment: But do jarvis'd portals not usually show "\_\_JARVIS\_\_" as owner and mod-installer? See [Jarvis Virus at Wikia](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/JARVIS_Virus). The portal in question (and it's mods) showed the name of an agent.

Comment: Depends on the faction of the agent using the Virus / Refactor; see edit.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129752/how-can-one-place-multiple-level-7-resonators-on-a-portal) is an old answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that during some special events agents can use more mods (such as the recent anniversary event).

Comment: God I miss these days! ;)
2 R8, 2 R7, 4 mods, that was awesome!